# Auto date with read only mode in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-forms

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #now = datetime.now()
        super(TestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['training_date']=datetime.date.today
```

How can we get auto today's date with a read-only mode in Django form?

I am trying to render my form with the current date in the read-only input field.

How can I achieve this, any solution??

I have tried multiple ways but did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the field by setting the [**`disabled=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#disabled) to `True`:

```
class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    training_date = forms.DateField(disabled=True, initial=datetime.date.today)
    # …
```

This will not only make the field read-only at the client side. It will ignore a different value in a (malicious) POST request.

Comment: I already tried this, and this is not rendering the current date.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It is working. But there is one problem with this - as I wanted the auto current date at form ADD(i.e with blank form init) and existing date from DB when EDIT(i.e. when editing the form data). But it is not allowing me to do that. It will render current data in all stages. Any suggestion?

Comment: @DeepakSingh: can you share your model(s) and view(s) that use this form?